# How to create an angular module as a bower package

Tags: angularjs, module, bower

I have an angular module which contains html, css, services and js. Now i want to use this module as a bower dependency in other angular apps or projects. I didn't get any proper documentation so if anyone aware of this pls share the process step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at bower docs: [Create Packages](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/)

Here is the summary of steps:

1. Initialize bower for your module and update the bower.json
2. Register your package using `bower register` command
3. Once, registered you can use your package in any app by installing it with `bower install <package-name>`

Comment: doc is saying about how to add our package in bower but i want how to make it as a bower package so if installed in other projects how can i route it to html which in the bower package.

Comment: well you didn't read the docs fully! once you initialize the bower, you need to register it : http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#register so that you can use it in other projects